# What is the proper way to index your site with Google Webmaster Tools?

Tags: .htaccess, seo, sitemap, google-search-console, canonical-link

I've recently revamped my website. I basically deleted everything and built everything from scratch.

Here is what I've done:

- Added a canonical tag on each page so that Google knows which version
  I prefer (my preferred version is www.mywebsite.com).
- Set a 301 redirect in htaccess which sends mywebsite.com to
  www.mywebsite.com.

  ```
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mywebsite.com [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mywebsite.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
  ```
- Created 301's for legacy urls for the old links of the same
  domain.
- Verified www.mywebsite.com with Google Webmaster Tools.
- Built an xml sitemap which contains the same urls that I've added in the canonical tags and submitted it to GWT.

Its been 7 days now and my sitemap status on GWT is still set to "Pending".

I've only verified the www version of my website...**Will that suffice or do I need to verify the non-www version as well**? The reason I am asking is that I feel its overkill to verify the non-www version since I already have canonical tags set on each page.
**Is it normal for Google to take so long? Am I missing anything?**

P.S. My site has been around since 2001 but its been almost 8 years since it received a major upgrade (not sure if this plays a role in how fast Google indexes my new pages)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To accelerate the process, verify the non-www site in GWT. Then submit a sitemap with the non-www urls and a recent `lastmod` date. It will help bots notice your redirects and canonicals faster.

You will notice the number of indexed urls go down in GWT for non-www and rise for www.

The age of your site is not correlated with indexing.